# grails javascript asset executes every page load without even being 'called'

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

I need javascript libraries in my grails project. I read that putting the file in grails-app/assets/javascripts and then calling it with `<asset:javascript src="myJSFile.js"/>` is the way to go. However, I notice that without even putting `<asset:javascript src="myJSFile.js"/>` ANYWHERE in my project, the file executes every page load...

I notice that all my problems seem to disappear if I simply remove the line in grails-app/javascripts/application.js: `//= require_tree .` But it feels like I'm doing something wrong...

I don't really understand the documentation (https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) well enough to know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The `//= require_tree .` says that the manifest should include all files in directories starting with the root javascript directory for the assets.

So, when you remove that it's going to no longer pick up any of your javascript files as a part of the manifest. Which gets included in all pages.

If you want fine grained control over what is included in the manifest then you'll have to remove the existing `//= reuire_tree .` and specify the individual assets yourself or configure the plugin to ignore your javascript entirely (which I wouldn't recommend).

Spend more time with the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#directives) as it's all explained in detail in there.